# oblique parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, geometric-transform

I'm looking from a sketch of the 2D rectangle style, like this :
`Extrude[Rectangle[{1, 6}], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]`
But I want to extrude it in an oblique direction in order to obtain an oblique parallelepiped, like below
[image]

Comment: How about starting with a `Cuboid` and applying a `ShearingTranform` on it?

Comment: Just use `Parallelepiped`.